# Can't get 32 bit Ubuntu to boot on a macbook

Tags: installation, live-usb, 32-bit, macbook

I have tried 12.04 and 13.04 and neither one creates a bootable disk. I already have 64 bit Ubuntu but need 32 bit for a specific program that I need to run. I have tried Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu, and tried several methods on OS X but none of them create a disl that will show in the boot options. I tried Penguintosh and that got it to show up and it booted as far as the starting kernel message but then it hung there for hours. I have tried redownloading, and as I said multiple methods of creating the boot disk. I've been trying to make this live usb for almost a week now lol. I don't have CD's. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not actually an app, it's a command line script calle Juopunut. It specifically requires 32 bit. I finally bought a DVD off of a friend and created a live DVD. It installs and tell me to reboot but when my computer comes back up, refind can't find any bootable partitions...

Comment: This question sounds similar, and may help:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/433949/what-is-the-recommended-release-of-ubuntu-for-32-bit-intel-based-macs

Answer (score 0):

The 32 bit image is for bios based PCs only.  You can install 32 bit apps on a 64 bit system.